# Sorting using multiple elements in python

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to sort the following list:

```
SKP3_CHU;20160101;0.0;Reproceso;
SKP3_CHU;20160102;10.4186115265;Reproceso;
SKP3_CHU;20160103;13.4833335876;Reproceso;
SKP3_CHU;20160104;16.0980548859;Reproceso;
SKP3_CHU;20160105;6.93333339691;Falta Espacio;
SKP3_CHU;20160106;5.93333339691;Falta Espacio;
SKP3_CHU;20160107;6.28138732918;Falta Espacio;
SKP3_CHU;20160108;13.0666666031;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160109;17.3333339691;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160110;17.3333339691;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160111;17.3333339691;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160112;17.3333339691;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160113;18.2833347321;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160114;14.0166664124;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160115;18.2833347321;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160116;18.2833347321;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160117;18.2833347321;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160118;18.2833347321;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160119;17.5166664124;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160120;18.2833347321;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160121;14.0166664124;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160122;18.2833347321;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160123;18.2833347321;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160124;18.2833347321;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160125;18.2833347321;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160126;16.75;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160127;18.2833347321;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160128;14.0166664124;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160129;18.2833347321;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160130;18.2833347321;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160131;18.2833347321;Falta Demanda;
SKP3_CHU;20160104;0.851945877;Falta Espacio;
SKP3_CHU;20160107;6.05194568622;Falta Demanda;
```

By using the following code:

```
regist.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(0,3,1))
```

But the last two items always end at the bottom, is the way I am ordering the items wrong, or should i add something else?

**EDIT**
Code for adding the regist list:

```
var = str(Linea) + ";" + str(bkt) + ";" + str(val502) + ";;0;"
regist.append(var)
```

I omitted some lines, that write some data in a text file

Comment: How are you reading in the data?

Comment: Can you add the code for how you load this `regist` list?

Comment: That is clearly not how you load `regist` - I don't see `;;0;` anywhere in your lines

Comment: What exactly are you trying to sort? By converting each column to strings, it will do lexicographical sorting

Comment: @inspectorG4dget the data of Linea, bkt, val502, comes from memory from another program, so i know what each column says bbecause of a file that specifies some functions I can use (this is from my company, and can't share this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you wrote all of that to a file:

```
import csv

getter = operator.itemgetter(0,3,1)

with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    answer = sorted(list(csv.reader(infile, delimiter=';')) key=lambda row:(row[0], row[3], int(row[1])))
```

Comment: Testes the line, made some tweaks, and with using sorted it did what I needed. Thanks!